# Lambda is invoked multiple times on s3 upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have an issue with a Lambda function that resizes images. The script is triggered on ObjectCreated event in s3, but when I refresh the s3 bucket, all of the images (created with the lambda function) have a changed 'Last modified' column (showing the current time), and I'm guessing that the Lambda recreates them.

The Lambda has a S3 event trigger with Event type: ObjectCreated on the specific bucket.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this issue?

Comment: Review CoudWatch Logs to determine if your Lambda function was invoked multiple times in response to a single event. If it was, then work out what (error or timeout) caused Lambda to retry the invocation.

Comment: Did you write the Lambda code, or did you obtain it elsewhere (eg [Tutorial: Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3 - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html))? Is it writing the resized picture to the _same_ bucket, or a _different_ bucket?

Comment: Hello @JohnRotenstein. It was an existing  function I additionally modified according to the needs. It's in the same bucket, just the resized images are in different folder than the original ones. Is the usage of the same bucket the possible cause of the issue?

Comment: Did you configure the event to only trigger for a given path (the 'originals' path)? If not, then the output file created by Lambda would be triggering the Lambda function again, possibly causing an infinite loop.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein helllo again. Thanks for the help. My guess was that the created images were creating the infinity loop. The issue with setting the prefix (gallery/) in the event trigger - the folder where the original images are placed, is that when I set it, the Lambda function is not being invoked on  S3 file upload. And I have no guess why the function is not being invoked this way

Comment: Well, you either need to get that path working, or save the resized images into a different bucket. You could test things by having the event trigger SNS or SQS, which is easier to notice than a Lambda execution. Try configuring the event in S3 rather than in the Lambda function.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein does adding of the prefix affect the source bucket in the Lambda? Because I must have the original and resized images in the same bucket. Sorry if I'm asking silly question here, but I'm a newbie in Lambda. I also tried to add event trigger SNS but a message keeps popping that the 'Permissions on the destination topic do not allow S3 to publish notifications from this bucket', although I have added the s3 bucket arn in the topic policy

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Update: I noticed why the Lambda is not being invoked. In the tree structure in the s3 bucket i have userId/gallery folders, and when I add the 'userid/gallery' prefix it works. Problem: the userID is dynamic, it changes depending on the user logged on the platform. How do I put a wildcard in the prefix?

Comment: You cannot use a wildcard in the prefix. However, you could add some logic to the start of the Lambda function to look at the path and only process the image if it is in a `gallery` subdirectory. Thus, Lambda will fire with every object, but will only process the desired incoming images.